# AT command parsing and listening for incoming SMS Arduino Leonardo SIM800H

Tags: serial

I am trying to make a program that receives commands contained in SMS. The commands can be $CMD1 and $CMD2. Of course I need to verify the phone number of the sender by its last 6 digits. Other than this I have to ask and receive rtc clock information from the modem. AT commands format:
+CCLK: "YY/MM/DD,HH:MM:SS+TT" (works properly)
+CMTI: "SM",N (where N is the index number of the sms in the phone mem)
+CMGR: "REC READ","+1234567890","","04/01/01,00:00:00+00" (it reaches only the 15th char and hangs)

My code:

```
const long interval = 1000;
static long currentMillis;

byte searchcharpos = 0; //To determine where is the + in +CCLK in the char array

char serialdata[256]; //Array to store the chars before parsing

char rtcy1[3]; //Current year  Format: yy\0
char rtcm1[3]; //Current month  Format: mm\0
char rtcd1[3]; //Current day  Format: dd\0
char rtch1[3]; //Current hour  Format: hh\0
char rtcmm1[3]; //Current minute  Format: mm\0
char rtcs1[3]; //Current second  Format: ss\0

char esemesemes[3];

byte pointingfinger = 0;

char enabledtime = 0;

char cclkenabl = 0;

char foundchar[6];

byte cmtienabl = 0;

byte witdqt = 0;

byte acceptsms = 0;

byte ocpos = 0;

byte occurence = 0;

byte cmgrenabl = 0;

byte esemindex[3];

char phone1[6] = {'5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};

char phone2[6];

byte enableclock = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //USB to Computer
  Serial1.begin(9600); //UART to Modem
  Serial1.print("ATE0\r"); //Disable echo
}

void loop() {
  if (millis() - currentMillis >= interval) //This is done every second
  {
    if (enableclock == 1) {
      Serial1.print("AT+CCLK?\r");
    }
    Serial.println("=========");
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 1]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 2]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 3]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 4]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 5]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 6]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 7]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 9]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 10]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 11]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 12]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 13]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 14]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 15]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 16]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 17]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 18]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 19]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 20]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 21]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 22]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 23]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 24]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 25]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 26]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 27]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 28]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 29]);
    Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 30]);
    Serial.print ("=========");
    //Serial1.print("AT+CCLK?\r"); //ask for the time
    //delay(50);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("=====");
    Serial.println(millis());

    if (enableclock == 1) {
      Serial.println("YEAR: ");
      Serial.print(rtcy1[0]);
      Serial.println(rtcy1[1]);
      Serial.println("MONTH: ");
      Serial.print(rtcm1[0]);
      Serial.println(rtcm1[1]);
      Serial.println("DAY: ");
      Serial.print(rtcd1[0]);
      Serial.println(rtcd1[1]);
      Serial.println("HOUR: ");
      Serial.print(rtch1[0]);
      Serial.println(rtch1[1]);
      Serial.println("MINUTE: ");
      Serial.print(rtcmm1[0]);
      Serial.println(rtcmm1[1]);
      Serial.println("SECOND: ");
      Serial.print(rtcs1[0]);
      Serial.println(rtcs1[1]);
    }
    enabledtime = 1;

    currentMillis = millis();
  }

  if (enabledtime == 1) {
    if (Serial1.available () > 0) {
      foundchar[0] = foundchar[1];
      foundchar[1] = foundchar[2];
      foundchar[2] = foundchar[3];
      foundchar[3] = foundchar[4];
      foundchar[4] = foundchar[5];
      foundchar[5] = Serial1.read();

      if (foundchar[0] == '+' && foundchar[1] == 'C' && foundchar[2] == 'C' && foundchar[3] == 'L' && foundchar[4] == 'K' && foundchar[5] == ':' && enableclock == 1) {
        cclkenabl = 1;
        pointingfinger = 0;
      }

      if (foundchar[0] == '+' && foundchar[1] == 'C' && foundchar[2] == 'M' && foundchar[3] == 'T' && foundchar[4] == 'I' && foundchar[5] == ':') {
        cmtienabl = 1;
        pointingfinger = 0;
        enableclock = 0;
      }

      if (foundchar[0] == '+' && foundchar[1] == 'C' && foundchar[2] == 'M' && foundchar[3] == 'G' && foundchar[4] == 'R' && foundchar[5] == ':') {
        cmgrenabl = 1;
        pointingfinger = 0;
      }

      if (foundchar[0] == '$' && foundchar[1] == 'C' && foundchar[2] == 'M' && foundchar[3] == 'D' && foundchar[4] == '1') {
        if (acceptsms == 1) {
          while (true) {
            Serial.println("CMD1");
          }
        }
      }

      if (foundchar[0] == '$' && foundchar[1] == 'C' && foundchar[2] == 'M' && foundchar[3] == 'D' && foundchar[4] == '2') {
        if (acceptsms == 1) {
          Serial.println("CMD2");
        }
      }

      if (cclkenabl == 1) {
        while (foundchar[0] != '\n') {
          if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
            serialdata[pointingfinger] = foundchar[0];
            serialdata[pointingfinger + 1] = 0;
            pointingfinger++;
            foundchar[0] = foundchar[1];
            foundchar[1] = foundchar[2];
            foundchar[2] = foundchar[3];
            foundchar[3] = foundchar[4];
            foundchar[4] = foundchar[5];
            foundchar[5] = Serial1.read();

          }
        }
        cmgrenabl = 0;
        cclkenabl = 0;
        //pointingfinger = 0;
        enabledtime = 0;
        rtcy1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]; //getting first char with its offset
        rtcy1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 9];
        rtcy1[2] = '\0';
        rtcm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 11];
        rtcm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 12];
        rtcm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcd1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 14];
        rtcd1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 15];
        rtcd1[2] = '\0';
        rtch1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 17];
        rtch1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 18];
        rtch1[2] = '\0';
        rtcmm1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 20];
        rtcmm1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 21];
        rtcmm1[2] = '\0';
        rtcs1[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 23];
        rtcs1[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 24];
        rtcs1[2] = '\0';
      }

      if (cmtienabl == 1) {
        while (foundchar[0] != '\n') {
          if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
            serialdata[pointingfinger] = foundchar[0];
            serialdata[pointingfinger + 1] = 0;
            pointingfinger++;
            foundchar[0] = foundchar[1];
            foundchar[1] = foundchar[2];
            foundchar[2] = foundchar[3];
            foundchar[3] = foundchar[4];
            foundchar[4] = foundchar[5];
            foundchar[5] = Serial1.read();

          }
        }
        cmtienabl = 0;
        //pointingfinger = 0;
        enabledtime = 0;
        enableclock = 0;
        esemesemes[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]; //getting first char with its offset
        esemesemes[1] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 9];
        esemesemes[2] = '\0';
        esemindex[0] = serialdata[searchcharpos + 12];
        esemindex[1] = '\0';
        Serial.println("CMTI");
        Serial.println(esemesemes[0]);
        Serial.println(esemesemes[1]);
        Serial.println(esemindex[1]);
        if (esemesemes[0] == 'S' && esemesemes[1] == 'M') {
          Serial1.println("AT+CMGF=1");
          Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
          delay(100);
          Serial1.println("AT+CMGR=1");
          Serial.println("AT+CMGR=1");
        }
        if (esemesemes[0] != 'S' || esemesemes[1] != 'M') {
          Serial1.println("AT+CMGD=4,1");
          Serial.println("Deleted");
        }
      }

      if (cmgrenabl == 1) {
        while (foundchar[0] != '\n') {
          if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
            serialdata[pointingfinger] = foundchar[0];
            serialdata[pointingfinger + 1] = 0;
            pointingfinger++;
            foundchar[0] = foundchar[1];
            foundchar[1] = foundchar[2];
            foundchar[2] = foundchar[3];
            foundchar[3] = foundchar[4];
            foundchar[4] = foundchar[5];
            foundchar[5] = Serial1.read(); //                       I THINK HERE WE HAVE SOME PROBLEM
            Serial.println("Searching");
            Serial.println(serialdata[pointingfinger]);
            Serial.println(pointingfinger);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 1]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 2]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 3]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 4]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 5]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 6]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 7]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 8]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 9]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 10]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 11]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 12]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 13]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 14]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 15]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 16]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 17]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 18]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 19]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 20]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 21]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 22]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 23]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 24]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 25]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 26]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 27]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 28]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 29]);
            Serial.print(serialdata[searchcharpos + 30]);
          }
        }
        //pointingfinger = 0;
        enabledtime = 1;
        occurence = 0;
        ocpos = 0;
        Serial.println("mode1");
        while (occurence < 7) {
          Serial.println("mode2");
          if (serialdata[ocpos] == '\"') {
            Serial.println("mode3");
            occurence++;
            Serial.println(occurence);
          }
          Serial.println("mode4");
          ocpos++;
          Serial.println(ocpos);
        }
        witdqt = ocpos;
        Serial.println("PHONE1: ");
        Serial.print(serialdata[witdqt - 1]);
        Serial.print(serialdata[witdqt - 2]);
        Serial.print(serialdata[witdqt - 3]);
        Serial.print(serialdata[witdqt - 4]);
        Serial.print(serialdata[witdqt - 5]);
        Serial.print(serialdata[witdqt - 6]);
        Serial.println("");
      }
      acceptsms = 0;

      if (serialdata[witdqt - 1] == phone1[5] && serialdata[witdqt - 2] == phone1[4] && serialdata[witdqt - 3] == phone1[3] && serialdata[witdqt - 4] == phone1[2] && serialdata[witdqt - 5] == phone1[1] && serialdata[witdqt - 6] == phone1[0])
      {
        acceptsms = 1;
        Serial.println("Accepted");
      }

      if (serialdata[witdqt - 1] == phone2[5] && serialdata[witdqt - 2] == phone2[4] && serialdata[witdqt - 3] == phone2[3] && serialdata[witdqt - 4] == phone2[2] && serialdata[witdqt - 5] == phone2[1] && serialdata[witdqt - 6] == phone2[0])
      {
        acceptsms = 1;
        Serial.println("Accepted");
      }

      /*Serial.println("");
        Serial.print(foundchar[0]);
        Serial.print(foundchar[1]);
        Serial.print(foundchar[2]);
        Serial.print(foundchar[3]);
        Serial.print(foundchar[4]);
        Serial.print(foundchar[5]);
        Serial.println("");*/

    }
  }
}
```

This is the Serial Monitor:
[image]

Comment: What is the exact question? You presented your project and your code. You want code for general AT command parsing?

Comment: I have some error that doen't allow me to see and parse the whole char array and get the phone number to compare. I cannot see what's wrong with my code.

Comment: That is the most bizarre serial parsing code I have ever seen. You're not making life easy on yourself with that stuff...

Comment: This might help you to write better parsing code: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/ and https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/splitting-up-text-in-c/

Comment: I also cannot comprehend that parsing code. You might want to start working on a general ATCmdParser like [mbed-os](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/platform/ATCmdParser.cpp) has or look at the parsing code from other libraries which receive AT commands ([example](https://github.com/ekstrand/ESP8266wifi))

Comment: Or, in short: Read an entire line into the buffer, and only once the line is complete do you analyse it and decide what to do with it. A sliding window is not what you want for line-based ASCII communication.

Comment: how to detect what command I have? I did this with shifting values, but is there a better way?

Comment: You could write a unified "send command and parse response", which will send a command, read the entire response in a buffer until a delimiter is reached, then use custom parsing functions or simple `sscanf` to parse the data out of it, according to the sent command.

Comment: `strncmp()` on a properly formatted line (c string) buffer is what you want.

Comment: Thank you both, I will see what I can do with the new info and write here.

Comment: @Majenko why there isn't a break; in the switch statement in your line by line reading example?

Comment: For `'\r'` there is a return, so you don't need a break (it would never get there). For `default` it's the last entry, so you don't need a break (though you could put one there if you like).  I should really swap over the `\r` and `\n` entries - the `\n` is really the proper one to detect for a line ending.

Comment: There - I've updated it. It was such a long time ago I wrote that snippet...

Comment: Argh! I hate Wordpress! It just trashed my post!  C  * N * S! I hope I just got it back in there right again.

Comment: I am really sorry, hope your site is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should throw away all your own code and read the serial data in a line at a time. Only once a complete line has been received should you then examine it to see what you have.

For example, here's something I just threw together based around a snippet I posted [here](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/):

```
int readline(int readch, char *buffer, int len) {
  static int pos = 0;
  int rpos;

  if (readch > 0) {
    switch (readch) {
      case '\r': // Ignore CR
        break;
      case '\n': // Return on new-line
        rpos = pos;
        pos = 0;  // Reset position index ready for next time
        return rpos;
      default:
        if (pos < len-1) {
            buffer[pos++] = readch;
            buffer[pos] = 0;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

// ... later, in your loop:

if (Serial1.available()) {
    // Read one character and send it to the readline function.
    if (readline(Serial1.read(), serialdata, 512)) { // do you really need 512 bytes of buffer?!?!

        // readline() told us we got a valid string. Let's
        // parse it.

        // If the string starts with '+CCLK: "'    
        if (strncmp(serialdata, "+CCLK: \"", 8) == 0) {
            // Slice it up by the different delimiters
            // starting at the 9th character:
            char *cyear = strtok(serialdata + 8, "/");
            char *cmonth = strtok(NULL, "/");
            char *cday = strtok(NULL, ",");
            char *chour = strtok(NULL, ":");
            char *cmin = strtok(NULL, ":");
            char *csec = strtok(NULL, "+");

            // Check the last slicing worked
            if (sec != NULL) { // It parsed OK
                // And convert each slice to a number.
                year = atoi(cyear);
                month = atoi(cmonth);
                day = atoi(cday);
                hour = atoi(chour);
                minute = atoi(cmin);
                sec = atoi(csec);

                // Show the time.
                Serial.print(F("The time is "));
                Serial.print(minute);
                Serial.print(F(" minutes past "));
                Serial.println(hour);
            }     
        }
    }

    // Do similar operations for the different possible messages
    // you may get.

}
```